# How do i show that coefficients of a given sum is all zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $W$ be a subspace of $V$.

Let $\{u_1,...,u_k\}$ be a basis for $W$ and $\{u_1,...,u_k,v_1,...,v_m\}$ be a basis for $V$, which is a extension of the basis for $W$.

Suppose $(\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i) + W = W$. ($a_i,b_i$ are scalars)

Then $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i \in W$.

Ok, here, how do i derive that $a_i,b_i$ are all zero? If $m=1$, this is trivial, but this seems nontrivial to me when $m>1$.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude that the $a_i$ are all zero.

Comment: I don't get it... Why do you want ($a_i$) to be zero?

Comment: @MJD Would you see my argument like after.. 3minutes? I'm typing it

Comment: @MJD Never mind. You're right.. I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i \in W$, $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i = h \in W$. Now, by uniqueness of representation with respect to the basis $\{u_1,...,u_k\}$, $h = \sum_{i=1}^k \hat{a_i}u_i$. Thus: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i = \sum_{i=1}^k \hat{a_i}u_i \text{,  or} $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^k (a_i-\hat{a_i}) u_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i = 0.$$
As $\{u_1,...,u_k,v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a basis (so linearly independent), this implies
$$b_i == 0, a_i == \hat{a_i},$$
which is as far as you can conclude: the $a_i$ do not have to be zero (which is intuitive: the vector $\sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i + \sum_{i=1}^m b_iv_i = \sum_{i=1}^k a_iu_i$ just translates $W$ to itself).